# Using Mathematica to compute limit of complex number that involves symbols

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic, complex

I want to use Mathematica to compute the Marchenko-Pastur density from its Stieltjes transform. The process is described in https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/02/02/254a-notes-4-the-semi-circular-law/#sasym eq(24) and eq(25). However, if I try the following in Mathematicaz:

```
Limit[-((
  I (-((-I b + c + Sqrt[-4 a^2 (-I b + c) + (-I b + c)^2])/(
      2 a^2 (-I b + c))) + (
     I b + c + Sqrt[-4 a^2 (I b + c) + (I b + c)^2])/(
     2 a^2 (I b + c))))/(2 \[Pi])), b -> 0, Direction -> -1]
```

which is just
$\underset{b\to 0^+}{\text{lim}}-\frac{i \left(\frac{\sqrt{(c+i b)^2-4 a^2 (c+i b)}+i b+c}{2 a^2 (c+i b)}-\frac{\sqrt{(c-i b)^2-4 a^2 (c-i b)}+(-i) b+c}{2 a^2 (c-i b)}\right)}{2 \pi }$, I will get 0 (here the $a$ determines the variance so I want to keep it as a symbol). Now I suspect the reason is the branch cut, but I'm not sure how to solve it properly using Mathematica.

Alternatively, I can also use the Plemelj formula, which says $\lim_{b\to 0^+}\operatorname{Im} s_{\mu}(\cdot+i b) =\pi \mu$. So in Mathematica I typed in

```
Im[-((-I b + c + Sqrt[-4 a^2 (-I b + c) + (-I b + c)^2])/(
  2 a^2 (-I b + c)))]
```

but it is not able to extract the imaginary part.

Updates: all $a, b, c$ are real.

Comment: This means that Mathematica is not handling multivalued function as desired. The Plemelj formula should produce the semicircle law as well, see page 55 https://arxiv.org/pdf/1712.07903.pdf.

Comment: Are all of the variables real? Which are positive or nonnegative? You need to tell Mma (and us) to help with the simplification. Don't expect us to read some article to which you link.

Comment: Perhaps `Asymptotic[...,b->0]  (*b/(c Sqrt[c (-4 a^2 + c)] \[Pi])*)`

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.